In Spring Data Redis, how can I create a listener of key expiration events for all topologies of Redis, from standalone to cluster to sentinel?
I've got a Spring Boot 3.3.x app, and we're using Redis with Lettuce, so I'm getting all the Spring Data Redis goodies via the Redis starter. Note that we are not using the entity or repository features, only the Spring Redis templates.
I need to subscribe to key expiration events across all keys, whether I'm running against a single-node Redis in a local container, a Redis Cluster, or a Redis Sentinel.  I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/78605153/969237, which is definitely a way to do it, but this feels like boilerplate that Spring Data Redis should handle for me.
If Spring Data Redis can sniff at startup which topology is being used, I should be able to invoke a single method on, say ReactiveRedisTemplate, that allows me to be notified for all key expiration events, regardless of the Redis topology.
Is there anything like that?  If not, given that it's now 2024, what would be The One True Way™️ () to do this?
